# Filtering executed queries in the Elasticsearch Percolate API

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I have this code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Deletes, then creates the collection "foo".
curl -s -XDELETE localhost:9200/foo > /dev/null
curl -s -XPUT localhost:9200/foo > /dev/null

# Creates two percolators called "barbaz1" and "barbaz2" with different
# values in the "plugh" field.
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_percolator/foo/barbaz1 -d '{
    "plugh": "xyzzy",
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "bar": "baz"
        }
    }
}'
echo ""

curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_percolator/foo/barbaz2 -d '{
    "plugh": "waldo",
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "bar": "baz"
        }
    }
}'
echo ""

# First filters out all queries whose "plugh" field is not "waldo", then
# tries to match those. Does NOT work as expected!
curl -XGET localhost:9200/foo/qux/_percolate -d '{
    "doc": {
        "bar": "baz"
    },
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "plugh": "waldo"
        }
    }
}'
echo ""

# Deletes the created percolators.
curl -s -XDELETE localhost:9200/_percolator/foo/barbaz1 > /dev/null
curl -s -XDELETE localhost:9200/_percolator/foo/barbaz2 > /dev/null
```

Which is creating two percolators called `barbaz1` and `barbaz2` and then running a document against them. What I expect to see is that only `barbaz2` matches, what I get instead is:

```
{"ok":true,"_index":"_percolator","_type":"foo","_id":"barbaz1","_version":1}
{"ok":true,"_index":"_percolator","_type":"foo","_id":"barbaz2","_version":1}
{"ok":true,"matches":[]}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you ask the `_percolate` too soon after indexing your percolators.

It will work if you add a `refresh` on the `_percolator` index before percolating :

`curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_percolator/_refresh'`

Comment: Right, this seems to be the problem. the percolator is real-time when it comes to only running all queries, but it's only (near)real-time as filtering queries implies a query, which needs a refresh to make data available for search.

Comment: I can confirm that this feature is now working for me. Thank you!